# Omitting values in a list comprehension, instead of using dummy values

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

My code:

```
new_list = [
    num * 0.99 if num > 40 else num * 2 if 20 < num > 30 else "delete" 
    for num in range(50)
]
print(new_list)
```

How can I have both conditions executed and the code will work without including the last condition?

Meaning that all the numbers that get the value "delete" in advance will not add to the new list, just only the numbers that satisfy the first two conditions will be added.

The output will be:

```
[
    62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 
    40.589999999999996, 41.58, 42.57, 43.56,
    44.55, 45.54, 46.53, 47.519999999999996,
    48.51
]
```

instead of:

```
[
    'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete',
    'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete',
    'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete',
    'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete',
    'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete',
    'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete', 'delete',
    'delete', 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80,
    40.589999999999996, 41.58, 42.57, 43.56, 44.55,
    45.54, 46.53, 47.519999999999996, 48.51
]
```

Comment: `20 < num > 30` is the same as `num > 20`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you want to limit the list comprehension by `if num > 30`:

```py
new_list = [
    num * 0.99 if num > 40 else num * 2 for num in range(50) if num > 30
]
print(new_list)
```

Prints:

```
[62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 40.589999999999996, 41.58, 42.57, 43.56, 44.55, 45.54, 46.53, 47.519999999999996, 48.51]
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- Use a loop filter; an `if <test>` part that comes *after* the `for` loop portion of the list comprehension
- Use a starting value in your `range()`; `range(31, 50)` only gives you numbers 31 and up through to 49.

The filter part would look like:

```
new_list = [
    num * 0.99 if num > 40 else num * 2 
    for num in range(50)
    if num > 30
]
```

A list comprehension has a *value* expression, followed by at least one *`for` loop*, but after the first loop can have any number of *`if` filter expressions*, that limit what iterations of the loops are actually used to produce the values.

It's fine to use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) for the *value* part, but such an expression will always output *something*.

In this specific case, it would be simpler to just use a more targeted `range()`:

```
new_list = [
    num * 0.99 if num > 40 else num * 2 
    for num in range(31, 50)
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `:=` operator if supported by your Python version (3.8+):

```
new_list = [ 
    v for num in range(50)
    if (v := num * 0.99 if num > 40 else num * 2 if 20 < num > 30 else "delete") != "delete"
]
```

`None` instead of `"delete"` would be a better choice.

Comment: You could, but you shouldn't. This is not helping clarity here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If the conditional expression were more complicated, your solution could not be applied, but this one would work.

Comment: My solution *definitely* can be applied. List comprehensions are very simple constructs, what you have here is not.

Comment: Assignment expressions do have their place, this is just not one of them.

Comment: How would you write for istance this comprehension without the walruss? `[v for num in range(50) if (v := num**2 + num**3) % 5 in {2, 3}]`

Comment: That's a completely different situation; you are talking about *efficiency*. You can just repeat the expression: `[num**2 + num**3 for num in range(50) if (num**2 + num**3) % 5 in {2, 3}]`. Or you can create a generator expression that builds the `v` values: `vs = (num**2 + num**3 for num in range(50))` and `[v for v in vs if vs % 5 in {2, 3}]`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was talking mainly about "Omiting values in a list comprehension", the topic of this question.  I do agree that OP's particular case has a better solution (yours or the accepted one) , but this solution eliminates the need for omiting values. Your Python knowledge is exceptional, but why you wrote that assignment expressions should not have their place in list comprehension is still not clear to me.